# Changing cisco ios description with python - excel input

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

What I'm going to do is writing an script with python to take an excel file as an input and then read the number and description of interfaces of a switch which is written in there , and then ssh to a cisco switch and change the description with the values added before in excel .
could any body give me a hint?

Comment: I've change the tags. `ios` is for Apple iOS - not for Cisco IOS.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking netmiko module.  I was able to do something close to what you require using netmiko but now I use ansible ios_command which is a lot more easier for a non programmer network engineer.

Answer (score 0):

Start with Paramiko or Netmiko , Netmiko is a bit better version. I would also just rethink about the actual project where instead of thinking about one switch think about all of them and see if you have some universal thing which you need to do in all of your switches instead of one.

```
For this project you could do below. 
1 . save date in CSV 
2 . Open CSV file 
3.  Create a dictionary and Save interface name as key , and description as values
4. Create a list where you can save all your keys --> l = d.keys() 
4.  SSH to the sw via paramiko/Netmiko . 
5.  Run a loop in the list l 
on each iteration send below commands 
interface l[i]
description d[l[i]]

this will translate to below 
interface eth1/1
description d['eth1/1'] ( d['eth1/1'] will be value/description of whatever you are gonna get from CSV)
```

If you really try to learn python then its a good start however if you are on a time crunch Ansible is easier option